# Azure File Share - Mount

Tags: azure, debian, azure-storage-files, debian-buster

I create an Azure File Share on my Storage Account v2. Going under the label `Connect` I copied the command lines to mount the File Share with Samba v3.0

I didn't achieve my goal. Error received: `Mount error(115): Operation now in progress`

Useless the link of Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-linux-file-connection-problems#mount-error115-operation-now-in-progress-when-you-mount-azure-files-by-using-smb-30

I have a Debian 10 fresh-updated ( yesterday ). I tried also with a docker image `ubuntu:18.04`, but the result didn't change, so I guess that there are more than my errors or possible mistakes.

The error is returned by the latest instruction:

`$> mount -t cifs //MY_ACCOUNT.file.core.windows.net/MY_FILE_SHARE /mnt/customfolder -o vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/MY_CREDENTIALS,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino`

My tentatives:

- I tried to change the version of Samba from `3.0` to `3.11` ---> NOTHING
- I tried to use `username` and `password` instead of `credentials` ---> NOTHING
- Using `smbclient -I IP -p 445 -e -m SMB3 -U MY_USERNAME \\\\MY_ACCOUNT.file.core.windows.net\\MY_FILE_SHARE` ----> NOTHING

Thanks for help.

Comment: The ISP blocks the port 445.

I find it running the Windows command `Test-NetConnection MY_ACCOUNT.file.core.windows.net -Port 445`

I took that from `Connect` feature, under Windows label